# Editing TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

Does anyone know how to change the values ​​in TableView?
I develop with SceneBuilder, so I am afraid, that any tutorial without SceneBuilder can't help me.

I tried to put code into the initialize method, which worked in program without SceneBuilder.
I also tried to set a method "setOnEditCommit " in SceneBuilder, but the method didn't start even after clicking on a row in the TableColumn.

**Edit:**

I tried this in the method initialize:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    ...
    //initialize TableViewu
    javafx.util.Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory = new javafx.util.Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
            return new EditingCell();
        }
    };
    vesniceTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cil, String>("vesnice"));
    souradniceTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cil, String>("souradnice"));
    pocetTableColumn.setEditable(true);
    pocetTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cil, Integer>("pocet"));
    pocetTableColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    pocetTableColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Cil, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Cil, Integer> t) {
            ((Cil) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setPocet(t.getNewValue());
        }
    });
    tableView.setItems(cilVesnice);
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    ...
    //initialize TableViewu
    vesniceTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cil, String>("vesnice"));
    souradniceTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cil, String>("souradnice"));
    pocetTableColumn.setEditable(true);
    pocetTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cil, Integer>("pocet"));
    pocetTableColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Cil, Integer>forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
    pocetTableColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Cil, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Cil, Integer> t) {
            ((Cil) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setPocet(t.getNewValue());
        }
    });
    tableView.setItems(cilVesnice);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand how to interact with JavaFX components that are defined in FXML created by the Scene Builder programmatically (in normal java code)? Is this correct?

Comment: I know how to interact with the JavaFX components, but I don't know, how to create a functional method setOnEditCommit.

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake.

**I forgot to set the TableView as editable.** `setEditable(true)` on the TableView solved the problem.

Comment: Could you clarify? I am actually experiencing this same problem. Your wording leaves much room for ambiguity.

Comment: My program works correctly now:) 

Mistake:
I didn't have 'true' on the setEditable in the TableView..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a controller class. In the scene builder, you need to click controller in the scene builder (bottom left) and then type the name of the controller class you will make. Then, click "View" and then click "Sample controller skeleton." Copy this into a java class of the same name as the one you set in the controller pane.

Comment: Thanks to your response, but I have the controller class already. Methods set in SceneBuilder for buttons are working, but the method, which is set as "setOnEditCommit" doesn't work..
And the initialize method, that I meant is in the controller.

Comment: Look into what 'commits' an edit. My guess is that you need to use one of the other methods, such as a key press listener listening for the 'enter' key or something, which triggers the 'commit.'

Comment: Where do I find, whats triggers the 'commit'?

Method setOnEditCommit should trigger click on the value.
In JavaFX application without SceneBuilder it is so.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Try 'find usages' or something similar. And as always, when in doubt, check the documentation for the method.

Comment: Yes, I use Netbeans.

And in documentation on Oracle does not write much..


I don't know where I find the answer, so I'm writting here.